# Is it possible to open another http server port in kdb?

Tags: kdb

Can we open more HTTP server ports in an instance?

`.z.ph` seems to handle requests on the same port provided at startup or during runtime. I need to open an additional port and have a separate handler.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on why you want this type of functionality?

Comment: The use case is a "metrics" only port from which an external monitor can hit (ie. pull) without impacting the standard handler.

Comment: what is the output you are expecting when the metrics port is called? A table or an HTML dashboard? If it is a simple table then you might want to call a function `http://localhost:4567/?metrics[]`

Comment: No assume json structured output. So i have this so far but i am not sure how to allow for different endpoints (/metrics, /other1, /other2). `.z.ph: { :"HTTP/1.x 200 OK\r\nContent- Type:application/json\r\n\r\n", .j.j .Q.w[] };` Obviously I lose the out-of-the-box table browsing.

Comment: try this `.z.ph: { :"HTTP/1.x 200 OK\r\nContent- Type:application/json\r\n\r\n", .j.j $["metrics"~x[0] ;.Q.w[] ; reverse .Q.w[] ] }; ` and call http://localhost:4567/metrics1 & http://localhost:4567/metrics

Comment: .z.ph: { :"HTTP/1.x 200 OK\r\nContent- Type:application/json\r\n\r\n", .j.j $["metrics"~x[0] ;.Q.w[] ; reverse .Q.w[] ] };

Comment: Seems to work better. (slight typo: Content- Type). I think i need to tweak the regex (?). If you /metrics -> ok, anything else goes to reverse. Need equiv of a case statement :)

Comment: I am glad that it worked. however please note that it will completely disable the normal HTTP request (because of the if-else), so you might want to resume normally if you don't recognize the `x[0]`

Comment: Agreed thanks for the pointers. This is one option anyway, short of creating a service around KDB and then getting the metrics server to probe that. Just exploring all the options.

Comment: Cool, just adding this solution in the answer section so others can take advantage

Answer (score 1):

To allow different endpoints in the URL itself, the `requestText` part of the input parameter in `.z.ph` can be used to execute different functionalities :

```
.z.ph: {  :"HTTP/1.x 200 OK\r\nContent-Type:application/json\r\n\r\n", .j.j $[`metrics~`$x[0] ;.Q.w[] ; (`date`time!(.z.d;.z.t)) ] };
```

As per [Kx wiki](https://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/dotzdotph) :
*`.z.ph` is passed a single parameter, a 2 element list of `(requestText; requestHeaderAsDictionary)`
`requestText` is parsed in `.z.ph` - detecting special cases like requests for `csv`, `xls` output and the result is returned to the calling task.*

Calling `localhost:4567/metrics` & `localhost:4567/other` will now return different results based on condition.

```
$[`metrics~`$x[0] ;.Q.w[] ; (`date`time!(.z.d;.z.t)) ]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to open two (or multiple) ports in the same q process. If you try to set the port using `\p`, it will overwrite the old port and start listening to the new one.

```
q)\p
0i
q)\p 1234
q)\p
1234i
q)\p 4567
q)\p
4567i
```

I think you can setup 3 processes (`A`, `B`, `Main`); set the process `A` & `B` on different ports and implement the handlers separately and then delegate the queries to the `Main` process.

To block the users accessing the `Main` process directly from the web, you can implement `.z.ph` of the `Main` process to something like following. This will show a static page to the user if he tries to access the `Main` process port. This way the user is forced to use the process `A` or `B` `HTTP` ports to execute the queries/requests.

```
q)con:"<html><body><h1 style=\"font-family:verdana;\">Blocked</h1><p style=\"font-family:courier;\">Web access blocked</p></body></html>";
q).z.ph:{[x;y] "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Length: ",(string count x),"\n\n" ,x} [con;]
```